# PCL Iterative Closest Point and other effects reporting empty point clouds

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

i am using PCL with a pre-built version (1.9.1 for Windows) and even with building one with the source code, but i am not able to have iterative closest point (ICP) or even other filters (e.g., normal estimation) to properly work.
here's my c++ code:

```
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <pcl/registration/icp.h>

void test(void) 
{ 
        typedef pcl::PointXYZ              PointType; 
        typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointType> PointCloudType;

        typedef pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<PointType, PointType, float> ICPType; 

        PointCloudType::Ptr pcA(new PointCloudType()); 
        pcl::io::loadPLYFile("pointcloud00000.ply", *pcA); 
        std::cout << "pcA size: " << pcA->points.size() << std::endl; 

        PointCloudType::Ptr pcB(new PointCloudType()); 
        pcl::io::loadPLYFile("pointcloud00001.ply", *pcB); 
        std::cout << "pcB size: " << pcB->points.size() << std::endl; 

        ICPType icp; 
        icp.setInputSource(pcA); 
        icp.setInputTarget(pcB); 

        PointCloudType pcC; 
        icp.align(pcC); 
        std::cout << "pcC size: " << pcC.points.size() << std::endl; 
}
```

and this is what i get in the output console:

```
pcA size: 19346 
pcB size: 19409 
[pcl::KdTreeFLANN::setInputCloud] Cannot create a KDTree with an empty input cloud! 
[pcl::KdTreeFLANN::setInputCloud] Cannot create a KDTree with an empty input cloud! 
[pcl::IterativeClosestPoint::computeTransformation] Not enough correspondences found. Relax your threshold parameters. 
pcC size: 19346
```

there is some problem using the clouds, PCL complains about their emptiness but they are filled, as it is written, with about 20K points.

can you please help me?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: well, i did not, just moved to another icp implementation due to project timeline.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to provide some parameters in order to have the algorithm work properly.

Having a look at the [API](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_iterative_closest_point.html) documentation, you can see that there is an example provided how to use the algorithm.

```
IterativeClosestPoint<PointXYZ, PointXYZ> icp;
// Set the input source and target
icp.setInputCloud (cloud_source);
icp.setInputTarget (cloud_target);
// Set the max correspondence distance to 5cm (e.g., correspondences with higher distances will be ignored)
icp.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance (0.05);
// Set the maximum number of iterations (criterion 1)
icp.setMaximumIterations (50);
// Set the transformation epsilon (criterion 2)
icp.setTransformationEpsilon (1e-8);
// Set the euclidean distance difference epsilon (criterion 3)
icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon (1);
// Perform the alignment
icp.align (cloud_source_registered);
// Obtain the transformation that aligned cloud_source to cloud_source_registered
Eigen::Matrix4f transformation = icp.getFinalTransformation ();
```

In order to get good results, you have to adjust the parameters accordingly to your dataset.

Comment: the problem is not about icp settings, even if i copy the documentation as you suggest the "empty cloud" error comes out from the flan kdtree.

Comment: could you provide the point cloud data? I can have a look and see that the problem is

Comment: Another point you have to know is that ICP does not work magically on every input. The two point clouds have to pre-aligned and ICP is then used to fine align the two pre-aligned point clouds.
And I mentioned that you have to adjust the parameters accordingly to your input.

Comment: hi serkan, thank you for your effort.
i am quite good in this field